# Multiple static files within separate Django templates (using block.super with multiple included files)

Tags: django, django-templates, static

I don't necessarily have a problem, but I'm unsure if this is good practice.

I'm working on a Django project. I've set up a base.html, navbar.html and sidenav.html and made separate .css and .js files for each. I have then included those static files separately in each .html file within separate blocks. Here's partial code, to explain what I've done:

*base.html*

```
{% load static %}
...
<head>
...
  <!-- CSS import -->
  {% block css_import %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'path/to/base.css' %}" />
    {{ block.super }}
  {% endblock %}
...
</head>

<body>

  {% block navbar %}
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
  {% endblock %}
...
  {% block sidenav %}
    {% include 'sidenav.html' %}
  {% endblock %}
...
  <!-- JS import -->
  {% block js_import %}
    {{ block.super }}
  {% endblock %}

</body>
...
```

*navbar.html*

```
{% load static %}

{% block css_import %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'path/to/navbar.css' %}" />
{% endblock %}

<!-- Navbar content -->

{% block js_import %}
  <script src="{% static 'path/to/navbar.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

sidenav.html looks structurally basically the same, also having css_import and a js_import blocks.

Now, I can say that everything seems to work just fine as apparently `block.super` takes blocks from both included .html files. Is that a reasonable way of doing things, however? It does require me to load static in each template separately. Should I just include all styles within the base.html? Or is there another simpler way of going about this?

Comment: This may be opinion-based, but FWIW, my caution would be that CSS occupies a global namespace. Loading CSS from multiple `{% include %}` could introduce clashes and unwanted cascaded styles, if not being otherwise handled by your own namespace conventions or a CSS processor. I'd probably consolidate the CSS and treat component styling more like a "theme", rather than trying to have component styling be self-contained within template fragments.

Comment: `include` is not inheritance, blocks from included templates do not collapse with outer `{% block css_import %}` because this is not inheritance, this is a composition of several template pieces. `{{ block.super }}` seems to be misunderstood as well: if `base.html` was `extending` some more base template, it would reuse most base template block contents by calling `{{ block.super }}`. In given code samples no one is either ancestor nor descendant of anything, `{{ block.super }}` does nothing here. [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)

Comment: @IvanStarostin I actually didn't think that was going to work exactly because of that, since super tends to use whatever would otherwise be in the template extended from. However, for whatever reason, it does actually use both of the blocks - the styling from all of the css and js files currently works fine.

But as I figured something is odd about it, is why I'm asking what the standard way of doing this would be.


Supra621 Makes sense. So it's basically better is I just use one styles.css for the base page and just import that.

Comment: Inspect final HTML of the whole page. If you're fine with what you get then keep it as it is.